# How to alter the value used to sort a view?

Tags: views, theming

I have properties that have a rental price. The rental price is a field collection with a value ***(price)*** and ***period*** (per month, per week). You can sort the properties by price (low to high, or high to low) using an ***exposed filter***. The problem is that if someone enters 2000 per month it is being registered as more expensive than a property that is 600 per week (2400 per month). So I want to divide the monthly values by 4 in order to have equal calculation.

**What hook do I need to use in order to process the value field just before it is used to sort the properties?**

Answer (score 1):

you can change query of view by this 
**hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query)**

[This hook is a core hook of views api but you can override it in you custom moduel like **MYMODULENAME_views_query_alter**](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7)

In this hook you can get parameters by exposed filter's and change views query based on these parameters.